# Aurelia, iOS, v9 safari throws Unhandled rejection (bluebird)

Tags: safari, ios9, aurelia, bluebird

I am using Aurelia-esnext. After adding polyfills, It works fine on all browsers and devices. However in iPhone 6s, 6s Plus or any iPhone having iOS 9 it doesn't load.

iOS 9 safari throws below error. Any leads on this ? It works fine in iOS 8 and below

```
DEBUG [templating] importing resources for http://localhost:9000/wwwroot/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0/compose.js []
DEBUG [templating] importing resources for http://localhost:9000/wwwroot/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-templating-router@1.0.0/router-view.js []
Unhandled rejection create@[native code]
resolve
loadViewFactory
load
load
load

tryCatcher
_settlePromiseFromHandler
_settlePromise
_settlePromise0
_settlePromises
_fulfill
_resolve
_promiseFulfilled
_settlePromise
_settlePromise0
_settlePromises
_drainQueue
_drainQueues
drainQueues
```

Comment: Can you provide your config file? It's hard to tell what else is going on here?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?